# What does "statically typed" and "free-form" mean for C++?

Tags: c++

In the [C++ tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info), it is mentioned that

> C++ is a statically typed, free-form, multi-paradigm, compiled, general-purpose programming language.

Can someone please explain the terms "statically typed" and "free-form"?

Thanks.

Comment: **Where** in SO is this mentioned?

Comment: @Oded: Click on the tag. It's the excerpt for the C++ tag wiki.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A statically-typed language is a language where every variable has a type assigned to it at compile-time.  In C++, this means that you must tell the compiler the type of each variable - that is, whether it's an int, or a double, or a string, etc.  This contrasts with dynamically-typed languages like JavaScript or PHP, where each variable can hold any type, and that type can change at runtime.

A free-form language is one where there are no requirements about where various symbols have to go with regard to one another.  You can add as much whitespace as you'd like (or leave out any whitespace that you don't like).  You don't need to start statements on a new line, and can put the braces around code blocks anywhere you'd like.  This has led to a few holy wars about The Right Way To Write C++, but I actually like the freedom it gives you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "this means that you must tell the compiler the type of each variable" -> Not anymore, you don't. C++0x reuses the `auto` keyword for *type inference*, so you don't have to annotate each variable *explicitly* with its static type. C++0x is still a statically-typed language, though :)

Comment: Thats a good explanation. to add to that other languages such as Java provides capabilities like "Reflection" that would help a class inquire about its own members : Thus offering dynamic typed potentiality.

Answer (score 9):

"[Statically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statically_typed#Static_typing)" means that the types are checked at compile-time, not run-time. For example, if you write a class that does not have a `foo()` method, then you'll get a compile-time error if you try to call `foo()` on an object of that class. In dynamically-typed languages (e.g. Ruby), you would still get an error, but only at run-time.

"[Free-form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-form_language)" means that you can use whitespace however you want (i.e. write the whole program on one line, use uneven indenting, put lots of blank lines, etc.). This is in contrast to languages like Python where whitespace is semantically significant.

Answer (score 4):

Statically typed:  the compiler knows what the types of all variables are.  In contrast to languages like Python and Common Lisp, where the types of variables can change at runtime.

Free-form:  no specific whitespace requirements.  This is in contrast to old-style FORTRAN and COBOL, so I'm not sure how useful this designation is anymore.

Comment: Python? Pretty sure of that anyway. Have this vague memory Pascal might too though uncertain.